# Referencing a value of a prior column in a default expression in xmltable()

Tags: postgresql, xml, postgresql-10

I'm trying to reference a preceding column `c1` in a default value of another column `c2` in the `xmltable()` function, but I get an error: column `c1` does not exist.

```
SELECT * FROM xmltable(
    '.' PASSING '<r/>'
    COLUMNS
    c1 Text PATH 'name()',
    c2 Text DEFAULT c1
);
```

I wonder why, as this precise usage is permitted by [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-xml.html) (emphasis's mine):

> If the path expression does not match for a given row but `default_expression` is specified, the value resulting from evaluating that expression is used. If no `DEFAULT` clause is given for the column, the field will be set to `NULL`. **It is possible for a `default_expression` to reference the value of output columns that appear prior to it in the column list, so the default of one column may be based on the value of another column.**

Comment: It seems to be a bug. For the sake of it I [reported it as such](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15426-e2cd2779c744a0ae%40postgresql.org)